# Is it possible to create a new table in SQL Server from an existing one and change the column data types?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a staging table from which I want to create a new table.

The staging table is all VARCHAR data types and I want to create a new table where I can specify DATE, INT and FLOAT columns.

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(int,Column1) AS Column1, CONVERT(float, Column2) AS Column2... INTO dbo.NewTable FROM dbo.OldTable;`???

Answer (score 3):

You can define the columns as-you-go:

```
select cast(col1 as date) as col1,
       cast(col2 as int) as col2
       cast(col3 as float) as col3
into new_table
from staging_table;
```

Alternatively, you can create `new_table` explicitly:

```
create table new_table (
    col1 date,
    col2 int,
    col3 float
);
```

And use `insert`.  I would still use explicit conversions:

```
insert into new_table (col1, col2, col3)
    select cast(col1 as date) as col1,
           cast(col2 as int) as col2
           cast(col3 as float) as col3
    from staging_table;
```

Comment: I would just use try_convert or try_cast considering the source is varchar.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . I would rather get an error, when going from a staging table to an actual table.

Comment: Huh... I'd rather test for NULL values than throwing an error.  Still a +1